# Создание классов для определенных задач

Tags: mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте.

При реализации небольшой справочной системы, состоящей из Студентов и Групп, по шаблону MVC встала задача создать классы-посредники, которые хранят информацию о Группах и Студентах, другие классы обрабатывают эту информацию, третьи - считывают и записывают, четвертые - работают извне.

Я так и не понял, для чего это нужно, ведь можно создать методы в классе Группа, которые и выполняют эти функции.

Пожалуйста, объясните, хоть на пальцах, что к чему.